# Can plastic grocery store misters be used for oil?

Tags: equipment, olive-oil

I’m really tired of buying oil spray cans. I know that there are relatively inexpensive misters out there, Misto currently being the most popular, it seems. But I’m seriously strapped at the moment, so even sixteen bucks is a lot!

Is there any reason two dollar supermarket plant misters won’t work with oil? Will they clog, or is the pressure not sufficient for thick fluids like oil?

Comment: Why is misted oil so important to you?  As the spray cans are also expensive, maybe pouring the oil or wiping/brushing it on for the time being would save you money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they don't work well. I've tried them.

First, the viscosity of the oil seems to be wrong for them. Instead of producing a cloud of oil particles, they produce a stream which exits with some force, like a mini water pistol. Second, the plastic of mine got softer with time, and I had the feeling that it also lost some color, so I suspect that something from the plastic leached into the oil.

It might be that I had unusually bad luck with mine, but I suspect that the physical properties of oil and water require different pump head parameters and the problem will apply to any water-intended model. If you are really strapped for cash, it makes no sense to make such a risky investment, since the chance it will work is not good.

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty sure that they’d be unusable with high viscosity liquids. And the plastic leeching into the oil is not a pleasant thought at all! I’ll break open my penny jar and scrounge up some loose change and get the real thing!

Comment: If that's what you want - personally, when I had little money, I wouldn't spend it on such a thing, given that simply pouring oil works well. But maybe you value misted oil more than I do.